# Is there a way to get JSON data without tying to model in django restframework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to get JSON data on my backend without tying it to a model. For example, in json data like this I want access to `quantity` but don't want it tied to any model.

```
{
  "email": "some@gmail.com"
  "quantity": 5,
  "profile": {
      "telephone_number": "333333333"
  }
}
```

My serializer:

```
class PaymentSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfilePaymentSerializer()
    # subscription = UserSubscriptionSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'profile',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        user = AuthUser.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
        return user

    def update (self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.quantity = validated_data.get('quantity', instance.quantity)
        print instance.quantity
        return instance
```

When I send a PATCH request, I get an error

> 'User' object has no attribute 'quantity'

Comment: I think model class defined in `Meta` should be `AuthUser` not `User`.

Comment: But that still does not resolve the issue of `quantity` being passed in the JSON but not being present in the model.

Answer (score 0):

you can use json

```
import json
json.loads('{ "email": "some@gmail.com","quantity": 5,"profile": {"telephone_number": "333333333"}}')[u'quantity']
```

I think you can use simple json too (not tested):

```
from urllib import urlopen
import simplejson as json

url = urlopen('yourURL').read()
url = json.loads(url)

print url.get('quantity')
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, passing an extra data to `ModelSerializer` and attribute missing in model will throw as you stated. If you want to have extra attribute which is not present in model, `restore_object` needs to overriden.

Few examples [GitHub Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435787/adding-field-that-isnt-in-model-to-serializer-in-django-rest-framework?rq=1) and similar [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396547/django-rest-framework-adding-additional-field-to-modelserializer)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
class PaymentSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    quantity = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_quantity')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'profile', 'quantity',)

    def get_quantity(self, user):
        return len(user.email)

    ...
```

Basically, you modify `Meta`, but not the actual model, to add an extra `quantity` field to the output. You define this field as a `SerializerMethodField`. The serializer will invoke the method `get_quantity` to get the value of the field. In the example, the quantity is returned equal to the length of the `email` address of the user. This is useful in general for computed fields. These derived fields are automatically read-only and will be ignored on `PUT` and `POST`.

Reference is [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).